# Azure data factory web activity with MSI authentication

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory

We are using Azure data factory to copy data from on-premise to Azure. We have implemented multiple activities to complete the data copy. Until now, we are using basic authentication for web activity to call web API methods.

As per the latest monitoring UI, it also supports MSI authentication. We have tried to use but no any luck. Also, tried to search related things but does not get any information related to data factory web activity and MSI authentication.

How can we achieve this authentication for Web Activity?

Regards,

Shrikant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can we achieve this authentication for Web Activity?

If you use the Azure function/WebApp MSI, you need to config the resource.

```
https://management.azure.com/
```

For other resources, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/services-support-msi#azure-services-that-support-azure-ad-authentication).