# How to use web activity to post a request to REST API in ADF v2

Tags: rest, azure, web-services

I have an requirement to process a table in ADFv2. For this I have to use a web activity. But I don't know how to pass the OAuth credentials to it. Because there is not an OAuth specific selection button. Below is the url to which I am sending the request

```
url - "https://northeurope.asazure.windows.net/servers/server123/models/testmodel1/refreshes"
```

Below is request body

```
"body": {
    "CommitMode": "transactional",
    "MaxParallelism": 2,
    "Objects": [
        {
            "table": "Customer"
        }
    ],
    "RetryCount": 2,
    "Type": "Full"
}
```

Authentication details used for posting request to API

```
Authentication - 
"authentication": {
                        "audience": "https://*.asazure.windows.net",
                        "clientId": "***",
                        "secret": "***",
                        "tenant": "***",
                        "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
                    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean your rest api is protected by Azure AD and you want to call the api in ADF V2, am i right?

Comment: yes..your understanding is correct

Comment: in that case can you please tell me how to do the same ?

Comment: Hi,if you think my answer helps you, could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use MSI authentication for your API in the Azure Data Factory Web Activity. Please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#managed-identity).

Specify the resource uri for which the access token will be requested using the managed identity for the data factory. To call the Azure Resource Management API, use `https://management.azure.com/`. For more information about how managed identities works see the managed identities for Azure resources [overview page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview).

Based on this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity),you could know that when creating a data factory, a service identity can be created along with factory creation. The service identity is a managed application registered to Azure Activity Directory, and represents this specific data factory.

So just grant the permission for the destination resource, then your adf activity could access the resource.

You could refer to this case:[Azure data factory web activity with MSI authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165397/azure-data-factory-web-activity-with-msi-authentication)